# How do I retrieve the correct size of native Windows controls?

Tags: c, windows, user-interface, winapi

I use this line to create an `EDIT` control:

```
hMyEdit = CreateWindowEx(
  WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
  L"EDIT",
  L"",
  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,
  10,
  10, 
  200,
  25,
  hParentWnd,
  (HMENU)IDC_MY_EDIT,
  hInst,
  NULL
);
```

Next to it, there is a `COMBOBOX`:

```
hMyCombo = CreateWindowEx(
  WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
  L"COMBOBOX",
  L"",
  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST| CBS_HASSTRINGS,
  220,
  10,
  90,
  200,
  hParentWnd,
  (HMENU)IDC_MY_COMBO,
  hInst, NULL
);
```

There are two problems I cannot figure out:

1. If I reduce the height (currently 200) of my `COMBOBOX`, this also limits the maximum height of the actual dropdown list. However, the actual height of the control *without* the dropdown list is not affected at all. Is the `COMBOBOX` supposed not to use more than the given height for the dropdown list?
2. How can I make my `EDIT` control the same height as the text field of my `COMBOBOX` control?

I was unable to find any documentation about default sizes, but I hope there is a proper way to size controls.

To sum it up, my questions are:

1. Which height should I apply to my `COMBOBOX` to allow the dropdown list to expand as far as necessary?
2. Which height should I apply to my `EDIT` to have the same height for the text field of the `COMBOBOX` and the `EDIT` control?

Comment: The combobox is compound control. There are child (WS_CHILD) controls - you can get their size. See `GetWindow` and `GW_CHILD`.

Comment: Thank you, @i486! Can you help me with my questions?

Comment: Create similar controls in a dialog box with resource file. Then read their real size (this is for 2nd question). Note that on different Windows versions or screen schemes / DPI size the controls may look very different.

Comment: @i486 I think there must be a more comfortable way to determine default control sizes. For example, how does the `COMBOBOX` get its standard size for the text field?

Comment: @i486: rather than using `GetWindow(GW_CHILD)`, you should use [`GetComboBoxInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775939.aspx) instead. It returns all of the HWNDs of the child controls, and the `RECT` coordinates of the edit field and arrow button.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ...Available in Windows Vista and above. This is not a big problem but is important.

Comment: @i486: don't trust MSDN documentation when it comes to minimum OS requirements. When Microsoft stops supporting an OS, they try to wipe it from existence, which includes updating MSDN documentation. Many things that actually exist in old OS versions now say they require Vista instead. `GetComboBoxInfo()` has actually been available since **Win98 and NT4 SP6**, and the equivalent `CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO` message has been available since **XP**.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are correct. Usually I use local installation of MSDN which correctly says Win98+. But in this case I looked in web MSDN and there was Vista. It is strange. PS: The reason is your link - if it was function name only, I would open local MSDN :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Behavior depends on the style you selected for the combobox.  If it is CBS_SIMPLE then the height is determined by the *nHeight* argument you pass to CreateWindowEx().  But if it is CBS_DROPDOWN/LIST then *nHeight* sets the dropdown extent and it figures out by itself what the height of the textbox portion needs to be.  Based on the font, sending WM_SETFONT changes the height.

> Which height should I apply to my COMBOBOX to allow the dropdown list to expand as far as necessary?

It is entirely up to you.  A sane choice is to have at least ~8 items visible. Consider the location of the combobox in its parent's client area.  You'd normally favor the dropdown list staying inside the parent.  But that's not always practical, if the combobox is near the bottom of the window then you have no option but letting it extend beyond the parent's bottom.  Beware the usability problem that this causes, the list won't be completely visible if the parent window is located near the bottom of the desktop.

> Which height should I apply to my EDIT to have the same height for the text field of the COMBOBOX and the EDIT control?

This tends to drive UI designers pretty batty, you can't get the same height when you give these controls the same font.  The combobox will be two pixels taller.  Text aligns properly however.  Strange quirk and I don't have a very good explanation for that, 30 years of appcompat can be hard to reverse-engineer.  I'd assume it has something to do with the space needed for the focus rectangle that is displayed in the CBS_DROPDOWNLIST style.  You could tinker with the font, giving the combobox an intentionally smaller font but that does not look very good either.  Anyhoo, use WM_SETFONT to ensure the combobox and textbox display text in the same font.

Comment: Thank you, I have to consider switching to a more modern GUI framework.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the `COMBOBOX` supposed not to use more than the given height for the dropdown list?

No, a scrollbar will appear when the content does not fit inside the listbox part. And you can even add `CBS_DISABLENOSCROLL` to force the scrollbar to be always visible.

> How can I make my `EDIT` control the same height as the text field of my `COMBOBOX` control?

**EDIT:** Use [GetComboBoxInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the handle of the edit part of the combo box (among other things), then use [GetWindowRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to gets its rectangle:

```
COMBOBOXINFO cbi;
cbi.cbSize = sizeof(cbi);
GetComboBoxInfo(hMyCombo, &cbi);
GetWindowRect(cbi.hwndCombo, &r);
```

Now the height is `r.bottom - r.top` and that returned `24` on my test, which is very close to the 25 you got experimentally.
That said, it's easier to use a dialgo box. You can create a dialog box from resource or dynamically using the [CreateDialogIndirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: I have made a previous answer using the `rcItem` field of `cbi` then calling `AdjustWindowRect` to take into account the style and ex styles of the edit control of the combo box, but this new version with `GetWindowRect` is in fact simpler.